# How does the find command know how many arguments to feed with "-exec ... {} +"?

Tags: find, arguments

In a command like this:

```
find /data ! -type d -exec rm -f {} +
```

the `+` is for batch execution of `rm -f`. `find` should batch as many arguments as possible. But how does it know the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit to `find`’s ability to batch arguments, when invoking a command specified by `-exec` with `+`, is typically determined by the kernel: it’s the maximum size of the arguments given to the `exec` family of functions. POSIX defines two ways to discover a value related to this, the maximum size of arguments *and environment* given to [an `exec` call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

The first one of these is a constant, which therefore ends up “baked in” to executables when they are built; it’s [the `ARG_MAX` constant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) in `limits.h`:

> Maximum length of argument to the *exec* functions including environment data.

The second one of these is available at runtime: it involves using [the `sysconf` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html), specifically with the `_SC_ARG_MAX` argument.

The limit set by `ARG_MAX` (which applies to both approaches described above, since both provide access to the “{ARG_MAX} variable”) is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), with regard to `-exec`:

> The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded.

The same is true of [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

> The *xargs* utility shall limit the command line length such that when the command line is invoked, the combined argument and environment lists (see the *exec* family of functions in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017) shall not exceed {ARG_MAX}-2048 bytes.

Various implementations apply these limits in various ways, sometimes applying smaller values than the above constants would indicate. For example, OpenBSD `find` checks `sysconf`, to determine the maximum command-line length, but also arbitrarily limits the *number* of arguments to 5000; see [the source code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/81a5d5c8702040f5e91cada2bc097ca40e7687ce/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c#L92) for details (thanks to [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) for the reference). GNU `find` checks `sysconf`, and falls back if necessary to `ARG_MAX`, or a `find`-specified limit; in addition it adds the 2048-byte headroom specified for `xargs` (GNU `find` and `xargs` share their implementation here).

Specific kernels can also add their own twists. [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/86440) discusses this for Linux. Solaris apparently requires different limits to be taken into account depending on whether the spawned process (not the `find` or `xargs` process, but the future child process) is 32- or 64-bit, because of varying stack requirements; see [`libfind`](https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/lib/libfind/find.c#l2020) for details (thanks to [schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120884/schily) for the pointer). The Hurd [doesn’t limit arguments at all](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/porting/guidelines.html).

Comment: Does `xargs` use the same?

Comment: Yes, `xargs` uses the same information.

Comment: But then, what does `find` do with that value? How does it know how many arguments to pass? What is `_SC_ARG_MAX` a maximum of? Is it the same on every system? Does it maximise that _arg length_ or does it leave extra room? Do all implementations use `sysconf()`, do they all consider the environment in their calculation?

Comment: Both `xargs` and `find` will also clamp the argument size to something reasonable. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472388/308316) about gnu xargs; but other implementation do that clamping too.

Comment: On OpenBSD for instance, the number of arguments will be limited to [5000](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/81a5d5c8702040f5e91cada2bc097ca40e7687ce/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c#L99).

Comment: @mosvy Giving it would have been better if yourfirst  sentence did not start in a way that makes people believe that there is only one  `args` and `find` implementation. Without looking at every implementation, I cannot tell whether all implementations check for all possibilities. `libfind` e.g. checks whether the program being called is 32 or 64 bit and takes the different limits into account. Do other implementations the same?

Comment: @schily ok change 'will' to 'may' in my comment; but if eg. solaris' xargs and find aren't doing any clamping, it would be better to state it directly. fwiw afaik gnu xargs and find do not care if the program  being called is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @mosvy The funny thing is that Solaris `xargs` only uses 255 arguments at max. So this will never hit the `ARG_MAX` limit. See what I am going to add to my answer soon.

Comment: @mosvy ready with my new text. You see, things are much more complex that you might have thought before.

Comment: @schily so, **a)** solaris's find and xargs do the clamping just like the gnu and bsd implementations, **b)** libfind's find is incompatible with other find implementations, because its `-exec` is not able to run executable scripts without shebangs. Please do not presume about what I may or may not thought -- I'm not sure about that myself ;-)

Comment: Did you verify that gnu find has such a low limit? It is simple to change `libfind` to support those rare simple shell scripts (I so far did never see a related problem), since it does not use `execvp()` but rather `fexecve()`. I would just need to leave room for a "sh" argument in my argument array.

Comment: @mosvy the next `libfind` version (available to the public in a few days) will include support for simple shell scripts (without `#!`) and it will do this using the full `ARG_MAX` size.

Answer (score -1):

I recently mentioned the general rules here:

[Argument list too long error with makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480685/argument-list-too-long-error-with-makefile/480742#480742)

A working implementation of this rule is in my own `libfind`: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/lib/libfind/find.c#l2020

The main problem here is that `libfind` needs to know the current environment size and whether the program that is beeing called is a 32 bit or a 64 bit program since there are different limits....

`libfind` makes this 32/64 bit distinction because before, I frequently did hit the limit when calling `find -name '*.c' -exec count -t {} +` to get the source line count for larger projects when `libfind` was used from a 64 bit shell while calling the 32 bit `count` program.

The solaris `find` implementation does not need to make this distinction since Solaris does not ship a 64 bit find and thus using the 32 bit limit would at least work in any case - even if it does not use the maximum possible arg list size.

BTW: for `find` it is unlikely that the unneeded additional limit for a single argument on Linux (128k) applies. For `make` this is a real problem since the whole shell command line is passed as a single argument. On the other side, `make` does not check in advance as `make` does not include code to split long commands.

P.S.:
I just discovered a funny limit on Solaris: both, `xargs` and `find` from Solaris call their programs via `execvp()` from `libc` and in case that the program to call is a srcipt without `#!`, the `execvp()` implementation calls the shell for the script and reorders the the arguments using a fixed size array. Since that array only has 255 entries, both `xargs` and `find` limit their arguments to 255 in case the command is such a simple shell script. If the programs is such a script and the arglist contains more than 255 arguments, `execvp()` would return `E2BIG`.

The problem here is: you cannot use `malloc()` inside `execvp()` since `execvp()` may have been called from a process that has been created via `vfork()`. If `execvp()` would call `malloc()`, this would result in dead allocated memory in the parent...calling `alloca()` on the other side always succeeds but may lead to a `SIGSEGV` in case that the local stack size is exceeded.